# In a finite p-group,H is a maximal sub group iff H is normal in G and |G:H|=p

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, maximal-subgroup

Let G be a finite p-group,H is a maximal subgroup of G if and only if H is normal in G and |G:H|=p
I tried acting H on right cosets of H in G .... I don't know what to do now...

Answer (score 2):

One direction is trivial: if $H$ is normal in $G$ and $[G:H]=p$ then $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ by Lagrange's theorem.

Let's prove the other direction by induction on $n$, where $|G|=p^n$. The result is true if $n=1$, because $G$ is simple.

Now recall that the center $Z(G)$ of a $p$-group $G$ is non trivial.

Suppose $n>1$ and that the statement holds for all $p$-groups of order $p^k$, with $k<n$. Let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$. Then we have just two possibilities: (1) $HZ(G)=G$; (2) $HZ(G)=H$.

In case (2), $Z(G)\subseteq H$, so $H/Z(G)$ is a maximal subgroup of $G/Z(G)$ and, by the induction hypothesis, $H/Z(G)$ is normal in $G/Z(G)$ and $[G/Z(G):H/Z(G)]=[G:H]=p$.

In case (1), $H$ is normal in $G$; indeed, if $x\in H$ and $g\in G$, from $HZ(G)=G$ it follows that $g=yz$, for $y\in H$ and $z\in Z(G)$; then
$$
gxg^{-1}=yzxz^{-1}y^{-1}=yxy^{-1}\in H
$$
By maximality, $G/H$ is a simple $p$-group, so $[G:H]=p$.

Comment: Rather than dividing cases, why don't you just argue that by maximality, $G/H$ is simple $p$-group and Sylow theorem implies $[G:H] = p$.

Comment: @love_sodam If $H$ is not normal, then $G/H$ isn't a group.

Comment: Ture but p-group is nilpotent so maximal subgroup is always normal.

Comment: @love_sodam Yes, after you've proved that every subgroup is subnormal. Are you sure this doesn't require the result we're analyzing here?

Answer (score 0):

The direction $\;\Longleftarrow\;$ is almost trivial, since if $\;|G|=p^n\;$ , then any maximal (proper!) subgroup $\;M\;$ must be of order $\;p^{n-1}\;$.

The other direction: if $\;M\le G\;$ maximal, then as a finite $\;p  - $ subgroups has a subgroup of any order dividing $\;G\;$ , it must be that $\;M=p^{n-1}\;$ , and normality follows from being  the index $\;[G:M]\;$ equal to the minimal prime dividing $\;|G|\;$

Comment: The fact that $G$ has subgroups of any order dividing $|G|$ doesn't imply (by itself) that a subgroup of order $p^k$, with $k<n$, should be contained in a subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: But in second direction we just have H is normal and |G:H|=p

Comment: @egreg Thank you. I didn't understand your point: I argued that $\;G\;$ has subgroups of any order dividing its order, and since $\;|G|=p^n\;$ this means those subgroups orders are $\;p^k\;,\;\;0\le k\le n-1\;$ . What subgroup of order $\;p^k\;$ did you have in mind?

Comment: @user297564 Yes, but then $\;|G/H|=p\iff |H|=p^{n-1}\implies H\;$ is maximal.

Comment: @Joanpemo Suppose $M$ is maximal; then it has order $p^k$, for some $k<n$. The subgroups of bigger order might not contain $M$.

Comment: @egreg If it is already known (or can easily be proved) that $\;G\;$ has a subgroup of any order dividing its, as written in the answer, then $\;M\;$ is maximal iff $\;|M|=p^{n-1}\;$ , when $\;|G|=p^n\;$ . It cannot be otherwise.

Comment: @Joanpemo I know that the result is true (I supplied a proof), but your argument is wrong nonetheless. A subgroup of index, say, $p^2$ might be contained in no subgroup of index $p$, so it would be maximal. Until you prove that a maximal subgroup is necessarily normal, you can't use that fact.

Comment: @egreg Thank you, but I really don't understand you: the fact that a group of order $\;p^{n-1}\;$ is normal in one of order $\;p^n\;$ follows from its index being the minimal prime dividing the group's order. I understand if the askwer doesn't know one of this facts (that there are always normal subgrousp of any order dividing $\;G$' s or that a subgroup of index the minimal prime that divides the order of the group). Then I, or anyone else, can prove that.

Comment: @Joanpemo But ***why*** should a maximal subgroup have index $p$? You didn't prove it.

Comment: @egreg Of course I didn't: after being downvoted sometimes for giving complete answers I try now, in order to be more in agreement with what seems to be more in the spirit of the site, not to give complete answers. Just like you said "remember that $\;Z(G)\;$ is not trivial". I can't see why this fact is more elementary than what I mention.